# jQuery conflict between scripts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, cakephp

I am using CakePHP and  am using 2 javascript scripts one of which relies on jQuery.

On one of these javascripts the $ variable is used which conflicts with jQuery and thus

I had to include the following bit of code in cakephp :

```
    <?php 
    $this->Js->JqueryEngine->jQueryObject = '$j';
    print $this->Html->scriptBlock('var $j = jQuery.noConflict();', array('inline' => false));
 ?>
```

This made the javascript + jQuery inclusion work fine. I then wanted to add another javascript which requires jQuery - which I have however I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function $(element) {  if (arguments.length > 1) {
for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
  elements.push($(arguments[i]));
return elements;  }  if (Object.isString(element))
element = document.getElementById(element);  return Element.extend(element);} has no method 'extend'
```

I am not a massive javascript buff. But this confuses me and obviously there is a conflict - please help me get this jQuery based script work.

Thanks,

Comment: jQuery's `$` is now known as `$j` and/or `jQuery`.  Edit your script appropriately.

Comment: This is the correct answer! If you put it down as an answer I can mark this complete! Thanks!

Comment: My comment is quite similar to [Jlange's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655223/jquery-conflict-between-scripts/7655246#7655246), and isn't quite as detailed about the reason for the problem.  I'd recommend that answer rather than posting my own.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the no conflict selector that you defined in the no-conflict section, i.e. $j instead of simply $.